# How to change default output path in ROBOT Framework

Tags: robotframework

How can I change default output path for a test suite in RIDE or by using CLI for ROBOT Framework?

Comment: Have you read the user guide?

Comment: I'm with Bryan, this is a very basic question that you could have discovered the answer to easily from reading the guide or even just a quick google search

Answer (score 6):

You can use "-d" or "--outputdir" parameter to specify output path:

```
pybot -d outdir test.txt
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the response.

Below is the actual requirement:
Email notification has been sent after execution of test suite with test suite report as an attachment.

Here I used Listener for sending e-mail after test suite execution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use -d to create output files. The default is the directory where tests are run from and the given path is considered relative to that unless it is absolute.

> Example : pybot -d C:\Work\Robot SampleTest.robot

All logs will be saved in C:\Work\Robot